# Is event trigger supported for Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-bigtable

Is there a feature supported like Google Cloud Function to be executed on Google Cloud Bigtable data inserts (data changed) which are then posted as events and then triggers a function to be executed?

The need is to query Bigtable only when there are updates/inserts.

Any ideas/recommended approaches would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no support for Bigtable changes.  The complete list of supported GCP event providers is in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling).  There are a few more provided by Firebase, but they do not include Bigtable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Bigtable Change Streams if you're still looking for a solution here.

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/change-streams-overview